# Prove that if $u_n\rightarrow \infty$ then $\frac{1}{u_n} \rightarrow 0$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Prove that if $u_n\rightarrow \infty$ then $\frac{1}{u_n} \rightarrow 0$

Could someone please point me in the right direction? I don't know how to show this at all. Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Hint: If you want $|\frac{1}{u_n}| < \epsilon$ then choose $u_n > \frac{1}{\epsilon}$

Comment: You could also use that $x \mapsto \frac{1}{x}$ is continuous on $(0,\infty)$.

Answer (score 2):

Since $ u_n \rightarrow \infty $, we have, $ \forall A \in \mathbb{R},\exists n_0 \in \mathbb{N}, \forall n \geq n_0, u_n > A $

Then, you need to show that for any $ \varepsilon > 0 $, there is an $ n_0 $ such that $ \forall n \geq n_0, \frac{1}{u_n} < \varepsilon $.

These do look very similar don't they?

Comment: Okay thanks, I'll give it a try